Is it possible to use the onEventName pattern/syntax for custom events in my own class?
I've written my own JavaScript class (for a custom web component). It raises a couple of events. For instance: TagChanged
To listen to this event, I (obviously) do this:
myObject.addEventListener('TagChanged'), (e) => doSomething());

But is it possible to have something like:
myObject.onTagChanged = (e) => doSomething();

The default DOM elements have things like onClick and onKeyDown. Are they using some other architecture?

I don't know categorically that there's no mechanism to support this, but I doubt it. Even if there were, the .addEventListener() mechanism represents a much superior architecture for managing event handling. It exists because the old "on" attribute linkage mechanism is so limited.

I'm pretty sure the answer is No. While it would be possible for the HTML parser to automatically recognize any onXXX attribute, I think it only recognizes the standard ones.

add a handleEvent method on (your/a) class, see answer


default Events  onclick and onkeydown. Are they using some other architecture?

Yes, Browser code us mortals can not access
But the Browser also calls a handleEvent method on a JavaScript class... if a mortal created it
From MDN - add EventListener

The method addEventListener() works by adding a function, or an object that implements a handleEvent() function, to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the EventTarget on which it's called. If the function or object is already in the list of event listeners for this target, the function or object is not added a second time.

So you can do
this.addEventListener("myEvent", this) // calls 'handleEvent' on 'this' class

which (by default) calls handleEvent IF you created it!
handleEvent(evt) { // handleEvent called by default 
  // check if "event_myEvent" method exists on class
  // then call as function(evt)
  this[ "event_"+evt.type ]?.(evt) 
}

Then triggers your method:
event_myEvent(evt) {
  // your event handling
}

Full code
Note: Events from shadowDOM require bubbles:true, composed:true to "escape" shadowRoots


customElements.define("handle-event", class extends HTMLElement {
  handleEvent(evt) { // handleEvent is called by default on every JavaScript Object!
    this["event_" + evt.type]?.(evt) // check if "event_NNN" method exists
  }
  event_myEvent(evt) {
    let div = evt.composedPath()[0] // Event from DIV escaped shadowRoot
    div.colors.push(div.style.background = div.colors.shift());
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListener("myEvent", this) // calls 'handleEvent' on 'this' Object/Class by default

    const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props)
    const newDIV = (name) => {
      const divEvent = new CustomEvent("myEvent", {
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true, // listener is on <handle-event> not on shadowRoot, needs to escape shadowRoot
        detail: {},
      })
      const div = createElement("div", {
        textContent: name,
        colors : ["red","yellow","blue"],
        onclick: (evt) => div.dispatchEvent(divEvent),
      })
      return div;
    }

    this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(
      createElement("style", {
        textContent: `div { cursor:pointer; background:teal; color:black; padding:10px }`,
      }),
      ...["FOO","BAR","BAZ"].map(newDIV)
    )
  }
})
Click row to cycle colors
<handle-event></handle-event>




Cool! By the way, you could've write this["event_" + evt.type]?.(evt)

Yes, alas JSFiddle chokes on it

Good call, I just tried JSFiddle, ? now works... that took them years to add. Changed to above code

It's in ES2020. I don't think jsfiddle uses any compilation by default, so it should've work since browsers supported it.

Not for me, and I use JSF daily. But Yeah! it works now

I don't see how the handleEvent method of event handlers helps anything with enabling to write <handle-event onMyEvent="…">?

It does not. Divide OPs question in 2 parts, 1) Can I write my own on* handlers: No. 2) Can I handle events (like) native Events: Yes, you can achieve something like that with handleEvent

You'd could implement something yourself, like this:
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    __ontagchanged = null;

    get ontagchanged() {
        return this.__ontagchanged;
    }
    set ontagchanged(fn) {
        // remove old listener, if applicable
        if (this.__ontagchanged) {
            this.removeEventListener('tagchanged', this.__ontagchanged);
        }

        // add new listener, if applicable
        if (typeof fn === 'function') {
            // create a unique function to prevent conflicts when using
            // the same function with the add/removeEventListener interface
            this.__ontagchanged = e => fn(e);
            this.addEventListener('tagchanged', this.__ontagchanged);
        } else {
            this.__ontagchanged = null;
        }
    }
}


Didn't get what conflict with the same function could've happen?

@Qwertiy Just prevents removing the listener like this, for instance:
component.ontagchanged = listener; component.removeEventListener('tagchanged', listener);
